# c++ terminate called after throwing an instance 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr: __pos > this->size()

Tags: c++, string, vector

Problem:

> Given a word quiz with m blanks, clues and a maximum of n words per clues (3<=m,n<=100)
>
> The first line of the input contains m,n.
>
> The next m line contains the word quiz and the clues you need to fill.
>
> The blank which you need to fill is marked as 1 and the one you don't need to fill is marked as 0.
>
> The output is the word quiz after we fill it.

So I try to solve as below, but it keeps being terminated. I am a beginner and this is my first time posting a problem, so any help will help me a lot!

***Input:***

```
3 8
011G1100
1A111000
00000C11
CAT
NIGHT
DOG
```

***Output:***

```
0NIGHT00
CANDY000
00000CAT
```

***Code***

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    short m,n;

    cin >> m >> n; //input

    vector <string> map(m); //map is the word quiz

    vector <string> clue(m); //clue

    for (int i=1; i<=m;i++){
        string dd;
        cin >> dd;
        map.push_back(dd); //lines of the word quiz
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i=1; i<=m;i++){
        string dd;
        cin >> dd;
        clue.push_back(dd); //lines of clues
    }

    for (int i=1; i<=m;i++){
        string str= map[i];
        int pos = str.find_first_not_of("0");      
        int pos2 = str.find_last_not_of("0");
        string str3 = str.substr (pos,pos2-pos+1);    //find the substring which don't have '0' 

        for (int j =1; j<=m;j++){
            string mclue = clue [j];    
            if (str3.length() == mclue.length()){    //check if the length of the clue is the same as the length of the line

                for(int k =0;k<= str3.length();k++){
                    if (str3.at(k)==mclue.at(k)){    //check if there is a similar letter between the clue and the line
                        string str4 = str.replace(pos,pos2-pos+1,mclue);
                        cout << str4; //output
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This line already has issue `for(int k =0;k<= str3.length();k++){` when you work with zero based array, you want `index < size` not `index <= size` in condition.

Comment: Recommendation: Run the program in a debugger, wait for it to crash, Inspect the crash site for more details so you can narrow down the area of interest that needs to be examined more closely. Step through that area of interest looking for the program doing something, usually taking  the wrong path or storing the wrong value, you do not expect. The unexpected is usually a bug.

Comment: Note that `std::string::size()/length()` is a valid index for `std::string` in C++11 and later, it refers to the string's required null terminator. But `size()`/`length()` is only valid as an index in `operator[]`, not in `at()`, how weird. However, the error message that is quoted is saying `__pos > this->size()`, which I don't see being possible in the code shown, since `k` can't be greater than `str3.length()` or `mclue.length()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed. It's the `substr` call that throws `std::out_of_range` if `pos > size()`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*It's the `substr` call that throws*" - that would have been useful info for the OP to provide.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just noticed that it's up there in the title actually :(but I missed that the first times I read it) :-/

Comment: @HuỳnhThiênBảo If you don't know how to work the debugger, print out `str.size()` and `pos` right before you do `substr` and see if you can't work it out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```cpp
> for (int i=1; i<=m;i++){
>     string str= map[i];
>     ...
> }
> ```

This loop is wrong. `map[i]` will go out of bounds of the vector when `i == m`, thus any use of the returned `string&` will be **undefined behavior** (including the initialization of `str`).  But you are not getting a runtime error on that because `vector::operator[]` does not perform bounds checking. Had you used `map.at(i)` instead, you would have gotten a runtime error.

Use this loop instead:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i)
```

Also, the `std::string::find...()` methods return `std::string::npos` (aka `std::string::size_type(-1)`) when a match is not found.  But you are not checking for that condition.  `size_type` is an unsigned type, so assigning `npos` to a signed `int` will produce a value of `-1`, which when assigned back to a `size_type` (such as in the `pos` parameter of `std::string::substr()`) will produce a very large unsigned number.  `str.substr()` throws `std::out_of_range` when its `pos` parameter exceeds the bounds of the string.

You need to validate the result of `std::string::find...()`, eg:

```cpp
size_t pos = str.find_first_not_of("0");
if (pos == std::string::npos) {
    // not found, do something...
}
size_t pos2 = str.find_last_not_of("0");
if (pos2 == std::string::npos) {
    // not found, do something...
}
```